# Create a mysql table from an html form that user specify the columns names and types

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a html table which is dynamic, it means that the user can add rows of inputs which contains column name and type, when he submit the form the data goes into an array. So what i want is to create a table from this form. It should be done be using a loop because the number of columns are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can take input type in loop too. Just think about it.

EDIT : While looping input tag and you want to get data in array you have to follow HTML array syntax In which you have to rename your input name attribute with postfix of [] ...